# Updating Same Record with Multiple Times at the Same Time on Oracle

Tags: oracle, design-patterns, sql-update

I have a Voucher Management System. And I also have a campaign on that system works  first click first get order. First minutes on the start of campaign, so many people trying to get to vouchers. And every time when they try to do this, the same mechanism works on the[design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc06c.png).

At the updating number of given voucher, I realize a bottleneck. All this updates trying to update same row on a limited time. Because of that, transactions adding a queue and waiting for the current update.

After the campaign, I see some updates waited for 10 seconds. How can I solve this?

Firstly, I try to minimize query execution time, but it is already a simple query.

Comment: You'll want to work with your DBA to examine the wait data for your activity, using v$active_session_history or OEM or some other wait-based performance monitoring tool. That will point to what the delay is caused by and you can troubleshoot from there. I'm afraid a forum like this can't answer performance questions without a lot of information that isn't easy to ask or give in a forum like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everyone is doing something like:

```
SELECT ..
FROM   voucher_table
WHERE  <criteria indicating the first order>
FOR UPDATE
```

then obviously everyone (except one person) is going to queue up until the first person commits.  Effectively you end up with a single user system.

You might to check out the SKIP LOCKED clause, which allows a process to attempt to lock an eligible row but still skip over it to the next eligible row if the first one is locked.